# Angular 13 Material menu built dynamically not working properly

Tags: angular, recursion, menu, angular-material2, ngfor

I need to have a category / sub-category selection component (mega menu).

I looked through numerous examples and also found an adequate [implementation example](https://github.com/shhdharmen/mat-menu-dynamic-data), downloaded it, ran and saw it has the same issue as me.

So I've come up with this example to ask for help from community: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nhb2gt)

This example contains two menus. First one is static and everything works fine. The second one is built using recursion and what is not working there is:

- Hover on menu item does not open it
- Menu items do not hide if you hover over other category or click on other categories

I would be very happy to know why is that, but I suspect this is a bug in `@angular/material`.

[image: menus not closed automatically]